# Automating repetitive game development tasks

Tags: automation, voice-recognition

Disclaimer: this is an open-ended and kinda "far out" question

Over the last few years I've made a few iPhone games.  I use very common programs like `Xcode` and `Illustrator` to make the games.

Lately I've become tired of repeating certain tasks over and over again.  Here are some examples:

- in `Xcode`: "clean target, build, run" over and over again
- in `Xcode`: delete image resources and then import updated image resources (identical names)

I'd like to automate these tasks in `Xcode`.  Any ideas?  I've done some automation in Photoshop using the "button mode" thing where you record a macro... that's been very useful.

Here's the kinda wacky or "far out" part of the question:  how can this automation be done via voice commands?  (perhaps using a [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/index.htm) product or something)

Here's an example of what I'd love to do via a few voice commands:

1. Save artwork from illustrator at a user-specified size (@2x versions as well)
2. Delete "`someArt.png`" and "`someArt@2x.png`" from `Xcode`
3. Add the updated versions of `someArt.png` to `Xcode`
4. In `Xcode`:  clean target, build, and run

I know this question probably seems bizarre...  but something like this could make certain things substantially easier for game developers.

Wonder if a combination of `AppleScript` and Nuance might work?